# How to change bootstrap 4.1 scrollspy(moving) active link color?

Tags: bootstrap-4, scrollspy

On top of my web page, I have a navigation bar with links to the different sections in it: 
[image]

When scrolling down the page, I want the relevant link to change color. 
How can I do it?

Full Screenshot : (https://eksiup.com/30f40ee79361)

My css code above;

```
   .custom-nav .navbar-nav li a:hover,
    .custom-nav .navbar-nav li a:active,
    .custom-nav .navbar-nav li.active a {
        color: #0AF3A9 !important;
    }
```

My html code above;

```
     <!-- Start Header -->
    <header id="header">
        <!-- Start Navbar-->
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg custom-nav">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/logo.png" height="33" width="94" alt="logo">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#about-us">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#feature">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#screenshot">Screenshot</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#price">Price</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#team">Team</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#faq">FAQ's</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link pr-0" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- End Navbar-->
    </header>
    <!-- End Header -->
<!-- Start Banner -->
<section id="home">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="banner-content">
                    <h1>Increase your productivity
                        with Firez</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                        magna aliqua.  </p>
                    <div class="holder-link">
                        <a  href="#" class="mr-3">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/app-store.png" width="161" height="55"  alt="appstore image">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/play-store.png" width="160" height="54"  alt="googleplay image">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="arrow bounce">
                        <a href="#about-us">
                             <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 banner-right">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/app.png" width="950" height="748">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rounded-shape-1 d-none d-sm-block"></div>
        <div class="rounded-shape-2 d-none d-sm-block"></div>
        <div class="rounded-shape-3 d-none d-sm-block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-shape">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/bottom-shape.png" alt="bottom-shape image">
    </div>
</section>
<!-- End Banner -->

<!-- Start AboutUs -->
<section id="about-us" class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5  vertical-image">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/about-us.png" width="800" height="820" alt="about-us image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7 sub-title about-us-right">
                <h2>Complete Firez once and use it anywhere</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  </p>
                <div class="row mt-5">
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 about-item">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/icon/fantastic-design.png" width="60" height="60" alt="fantastic-design icon">
                            <div class="mt-4">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Fantastic Design</h5>
                                <p class="card-text mt-0">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 about-item">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/icon/security.png" width="60" height="60" alt="security icon">
                            <div class="mt-4">
                                <h5 class="card-title">High Security</h5>
                                <p class="card-text mt-0">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 about-item">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/icon/options.png" width="60" height="60" alt="options icon">
                            <div class="mt-4">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Advanced Options</h5>
                                <p class="card-text mt-0">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- End AboutUs -->
```

Comment: Maybe a sceenshot, or a better description would help to understand your problem

Comment: I've added you can look.

Comment: Thanks. I improved the description to help those who can help you, as well as those that can benifit from answers to your question in the future. If I missed a point, feel free to inprove it further.

Comment: That's better. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Change css code above;

```
.navbar-nav a.nav-link.active {
    color: #0AF3A9 !important;
}
```